# Drtsn32.exe only catching exception once per reboot

Tags: drwatson

I'm trying to setup Drwtsn32.exe as the crash handler on a windows xp embedded system.  I have run drwtsn32.exe -i from the prompt to install it as the default handler.  Then I added a couple different fragments that would cause exceptions into our application as a test:

```
  int y = 0;
  int j = 0;
  j /= y;
  int* p = 0;
    (*p) = 0;
```

When I run our application for the first time, I get a Drwtsn32.exe popup correctly, the application closes, and drwtsn32.log is written and shows my crash.  When I run the same application again, I get no popup, and no log is written.  This repeats until I reboot, when the popup and log are both generated a single time, then the problem persists.

On a different system, I see different functionality - drwtsn32.exe does not generate an error (although I do see the MS Send Report popup) and the log is generated every single time, without requiring a reboot.

Does anyone know if I am missing a configuration option, or if a component is missing in our Windows XP Embedded Image?

Thanks

Comment: Some additional information that changes some things.  I wrote a simple console app with the same code above, and Dr Watson works after every run of the console app now, without restarting.  Does that help anyone?